# How to read the time out of an analogue watch?

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to computer vision and I would like to, given a picture of an analogue watch ([like so](http://www.ablogtowatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Patek-Philippe-5270R-001-Perpetual-Calendar-Chronograph-aBlogtoWatch-12.jpg) => 10:09:00), automatically read the time on the watch.

I've done some reading around and experiments with opencv and the best way seems to first extract the [face of the watch from the environment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNSFCFFQ-5E) and then apply the [hough probabilistic function to extract the hands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091836/reading-time-from-analog-clock-using-hough-line-transform-in-python-opencv). Then, with the lines and their angles, compute the time.

While this sounds great, I am having trouble to find code sample to get started. 
Do you know of any code samples, blogs, youtube videos, tutorials, libraries that I can piece together to achieve my goal?

Is my understanding on how to do it any good?

Here's where I am at

[image: Watch face detection]
*Watch face detection*

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Mat src, gray;
  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );resize(src,src,Size(640,480));
  cvtColor( src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  imshow("Input", src);

  // Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
  GaussianBlur( gray, gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

  vector<Vec3f> circles;

  // Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
  HoughCircles( gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30, 200, 50, 0, 0 );

  // Draw the circles detected
  for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
  {
      Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
      int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);     
      circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );// circle center     
      circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );// circle outline
      cout << "center : " << center << "\nradius : " << radius << endl;
   }

  imshow( "Circle Detection", src );

  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

[image]
*Line detection*

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat src = imread(argv[1], 0);

    Mat dst, cdst, pdst;
    Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3); 
    cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR); 
    cvtColor(dst, pdst, CV_GRAY2BGR); 

    vector<Vec2f> lines;
    // detect lines
    HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 122, 0, 0 );

    // draw lines
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line( cdst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    imshow("source", src);
    imshow("Hough detected lines", cdst);


    vector<Vec4i> plines;
    HoughLinesP(dst, plines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 50, 10 );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < plines.size(); i++ )
    {
        Vec4i l = plines[i];
        // draw the lines
        line( pdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }
  imshow("Probabilistic Hough detected lines", pdst);

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example image that you have posted is a pretty hard one. But the approach is fairly good.

If you want to continue building up on this approach, it might be a good idea to remove lines that are outside the circles and do not cross the neighborhood of the centers of the circles. Then you will need a way to isolate hour and minute hands.

If you can find a few hundred images, training a Haar classifier to detect watches will be better than Hough circles. It will also be neat to train a deep neural network to tell the time by looking at the cropped image of the watch.